# How to get callback values ​from php class to ajax .done

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a class that processes the data of a form that does a submit in ajax.

Everything works and I can store the values ​​to the wp database but I can't figure out how to get the $response->body value back from the class to the ajax .done function.

This is the class that manages the json of the ajax

```
 public function __construct($plugin_name, $version) {

    $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
    $this->version = $version;
    add_action('wp_ajax_save_cc_dado_settings', array($this, 'save_cc_dado_settings'));
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_cc_dado_settings', array($this, 'save_cc_dado_settings'));
}
 
 public function save_cc_dado_settings() {

    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'save_cc_dado_settings') {

        parse_str($_POST['dati'], $searcharray);
        if ($searcharray['chiave_licenza'] != ''):
            $data = array('domain' => get_site_url());
            $response = Requests::post('https://api.registroconsensi.it/wp_checker.php', array(), $data);

           echo '<pre>';
           $parsing_dati = json_decode($response->body, true);
           echo '</pre>';
           echo 'Chiave Licenza=' . $searcharray['chiave_licenza'];

            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->update('wp_options',
                    array('option_value' => $searcharray['chiave_licenza']),
                    array('option_name' => 'chiave_licenza'),
                    array('%s', '%s')
            );

           return wp_send_json_success($response->body);

        else:
            echo 'failed';
        endif;
    }
    wp_die();
}
}
```

and this is my ajax code:

```
(function ($) {
'use strict';


$(window).load(function () {

    $('#form_attivazione').submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();            

        var ajax_form_data2 = $("#form_attivazione").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl_arr.ajax_url, // domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'save_cc_dado_settings',
                dati: ajax_form_data2
            }
        })

                .always(function () {
                    event.target.reset();

                })

                .done(function (response) {

                    $("#answare").html(response);
                })

                .fail(function () {
                    $(" #answare ").html("<h2>Something went wrong.</h2><br>");
                });
    });

});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't send `$response` itself? Why are you sending back `$response->body`? Do you get an error? If so, please include it in your question!

Comment: well i can return $response but nothing happen anyway
if i use  return wp_send_json_success($response); i have .fail triggered